# how to serve multiple service of a container via https in GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I followed the tutorial on [kube-lego](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego/tree/master/examples/gce).

It works perfectly when I only have one service that needs to be accessed via HTTPS protocol. However, if I have following

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platform
spec:
  type: nodePort
  ports:

    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8002
      nodePort: 30082
      name: grpc

    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8005
      nodePort: 30085
      name: "8005"

    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
      nodePort: 30567
      name: "5672"

    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8011
      nodePort: 30811
      name: "8011"

    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8008
      nodePort: 30808
      name: "flow"

  selector:
    run: platform
```

then I have no idea how to serve all of them via HTTPS protocol because I can only set one of them to port 80. e.g.

```
- protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort:8008
      nodePort: 30808
      name: "flow
```

Ingress only supports service port 80/443 I have no idea how to serve multiple ports from a single container via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

you need the Ingress to help you,

because Ingress is routing by domain name ,so it can support mutli service with https,

use the ingress controller and set  hostnetwork true like this [yaml](https://github.com/kweisamx/kubernetes_ingress_letsencrypt/blob/master/nginx-ingress-daemonset.yaml),

and set ingress like this [yaml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kweisamx/kubernetes_ingress_letsencrypt/master/ingress.yaml), then check whether the http can 
connect to any service by each domain name,

if can, then add license to build https connect

Good Luck